# Sharepoint Get all lists Data c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a few problems regarding SharePoint web site and C# Integration.
I have a SharePoint Web Site & I can add files,videos into this site.
I have Specific UI design for this site.but actually i cannot add my UI design inside this SharePoint web site(I'm not sure about this.still i'm new to SharePoint.)
because of that i decided to take following steps.

1. Create Asp.Net MVC Web Site and Add My UI design Inside that site.
2. Access My SharePoint site from asp.net MVC web site.

In my 2nd step my process should be like this..

2.1 Inside some search box ,user can search 
but in here all data should come from SharePoint data(file names,video names that i have been added)those files name should be loaded to search box like google search.

2.2 when user select 1 file name and press search button then he should navigate to SharePoint web site.

My SharePoint  web site is now complete.i can add videos search those things using name, can do.but this search part i need to do from my asp.net MVC web site.

so how should i do this?

I saw SharePoint use rest api.but i cannot find good resource regarding that.
most of SharePoint tutorials come's for Visual Studio - SharePoint - SharePoint Solutions Projects.

But I need to do this inside my Asp.Net MVC Application.

i tried to do like this
[How to: Retrieve Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538683(v=office.14).aspx)

but its not success & i'm using SharePoint 2013 online version

---

**Edit**

This Code I tried.but not sucess.right now i tried to retrieved to data to my label or text box.

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

string siteUrl = "http://SMit.sharepoint.com/MySiteName";

SP.ClientContext clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
SP.Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
SP.ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

clientContext.Load(collList);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (SP.List oList in collList)
{
    label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + oList.Title +""+ oList.Created.ToString();
    //Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} Created: {1}", oList.Title, oList.Created.ToString());
}
```

Following method also i tried

```
  string siteUrl = "http://SMit.sharepoint.com/MySiteName";

    using (SP.ClientContext spcontext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl))
                {
                    spcontext.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
                    spcontext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new SP.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("userID@ddd.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
                    spcontext.Load(spcontext.Web, w => w.Title, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl, w => w.Lists);
                    spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                    //Console.WriteLine(spcontext.Web.ServerRelativeUrl); 
//I haven done anything here.i want to check  spcontext.ExecuteQuery(); works or //not.
                }
```

but Now i'm getting following kind of an error.
Error Occured on 
 spcontext.ExecuteQuery();

**An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
Additional information: The user's login name or password is not valid.**

Comment: You should post the code you tried using already and in what way it did not work. Otherwise no one will know why it is not working

Comment: I did update my question.but i already added that url. but that one is basic one.i think i should give authentication also.

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Yes I'm Getting 
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
-----
Additional information: Cannot contact site at the specified URL http://SMit.sharepoint.com/MySiteName.

Comment: Okay which line is that on? Did you try changing the url to `https://Smit.sharepoint.com/MySiteame` or removing the `MySiteName` from the url? also can you successfully ping the url you are using from that computer?

Comment: its coming from  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: Yes I tried it different ways...but its not successful.i can Ping 
https://Smit.sharepoint.com but cannot ping this url. https://Smit.sharepoint.com/MySiteame.it says ping request could not find host

Comment: Do you get a different error message when you call `ExecuteQuery` on `@"http://smit.sharepoint.com"`? Can you get to the site when you type that address into your browser?

Comment: same error for both links.
yes i can redirect into my site using both links.
but another thing here.how i give my credentials? 
because i already logged into my site.so i can erdirect using this url.but when i tried this using private browsing then i needed to login https://login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: you can use `clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");`

Comment: Actually same result i'm getting after add 
  clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("tdm@smit.onmicrosoft.com", "password", "domain");

above line.still my error is Cannot contact site at the specified

Answer (score 0):

var securePassword = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in "Password")
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
spContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@domain.onmicrosoft.com", securePassword);

Comment: Did you use url to generate the spContext object?

Sorry for the late reply.